# How to match this value?

Tags: php, arrays

So I am writing something to add on to my website.

I have this value stated above:

```
$settings[] = array(
    "name" => "torblock_redirecturl",
    "title" => $lang->redirecturl,
    "optionscode" => "text",
    "disporder" => 1,
    "value" => denied.php,
    "gid" => $gid
```

There will be a setting that where someone can enter another url or page. But I have this later in the php file:

```
die('$torblock_redirecturl');
```

I want that to change to the value in the setting once the setting is changed.

Aka once a value is entered in the setting, I want the value to change to whatever was entered right in the die.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `die($settings['name']);`?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'value' (T_STRING)

Comment: `$settings[] = array(` should be replaced with `$settings = array(`

Answer (score 0):

You were assigning multidimensional array.

```
$settings[] = array( "value" => denied.php);
```

So to get the value access like `$settings[0]['value'];` the index `0` changes according to number of arrays stored in the `$settings`

To get expected

```
die($settings[0]['value']);
```

**Update :**

If assigning as single dimensional array.

```
$settings = array( "value" => denied.php);
```

Then access it like `die($settings['value']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
die($settings[0]['name']);
```

It would be easier to help if you supplied more context, but your syntax error could imply that you wrap an array variable in quotes without escaping, like so:

```
die('$settings['name']'); // this will break
```

If you prefer wrapping variables in quotes, you can do it like so:

```
die("{$settings[0]['name']}");
```

You may be aware of this, but in your code you're not just assigning an array to the `$settings` variable:

```
// this:
$settings[] = array('name' => 'foo');

// is the same as doing this:
$settings = array();
array_push($settings, array('name' => 'foo'));
```